# Differences in WCF 2.0 framework vs WCF 3.5 framework

Tags: wcf

I am wondering if there are any updates / differences to WCF from 2.0 framework to the 3.5 framework?

Thanks

Comment: WCF was introduced in .NET **3.0** only - there's no WCF in .NET 2.0

Comment: Thanks Marc. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summary is here:
http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2008/05/12/50909.aspx